# WebGL - Reverse transform to retrieve vertex position from gl_Position in the vertex shader

Tags: webgl, vertex-shader

In my simple WebGL app, I calculate gl_position (of the vertex shader) as follow:

```
gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
```

aVertexPosition contains the (world-coordinate) vertex position.

I have been trying to do a reverse transform with gl_position to get aVertexPosition's values (x, y and z) back but it seems that the process is a bit tricky for me.

The data and matrices I used in the app:

- Projection matrix:

  ```
  [1.0282340049743652, 0,                  0,                    0, 
  0,                   1.5423510074615479, 0,                    0, 
  0,                   0,                  -1.0004000663757324, -1, 
  0,                   0,                  -20.00400161743164,   0]
  ```
- Model-View Matrix:

  ```
  [203830718994,          0.563721776008606,   -0.5349519848823547, 0, 
  -3.6513849721586666e-9, 0.6883545517921448,   0.7253743410110474, 0, 
  0.7771459817886353,     -0.45649290084838867, 0.4331955313682556, 0, 
  -0.00007212938362499699,-1000,                -9290,              1]
  ```
- aVertexPosition: [10.0, 15.0, 72.0]
- vertex: is the homogeneous version of aVertexPosition: [10.0, 15.0, 72.0, 1.0]

I have followed this approach for simulating the process of calculating gl_position in the vertex shader:

```
    mat4.multiply(mvpro, modelViewMatrix,projectionMatrix);
    vec4.transformMat4(vertex, vertex, mvpro);
```

As a result of the above calculations, I got the new vertex (should be the same with the values in gl_position):

```
    [-65.04684448242188, 72063.734375, 668851.375, -72 ]
```

Then, I applied the following reverse transform to obtain the original vertex's coordinates back:

```
    mat4.invert(invMvpro,mvpro);
    vec4.transformMat4(vertex,vertex, invMvpro);
```

Now vertex is :

```
    [10.014994621276855, 14.986272811889648, 72, 1.0005537271499634].
```

As you can see, the above values are slightly off compared to the original ones [10, 15, 72].

I used glMatrix version 2 for all the calculations.

Comment: No offense, but your matrices are impossible to read... can you put them in a code block and align to columns and rows on new lines? It also appears you discovered why single-precision floating-point's not always adequate and why order of operations in floating-point is so important for keeping what limited precision you have :)

Comment: Sorry for the poor format. Hope the revised version looks ok. Also, the matrices are a bit strange since I actually used a series of mat4.perspective, mat4.translate and mat4.rotate (glMatrix methods) to form them. If the slightly-off values are caused by the problem of floating-point precision it should be ok. I just want to know whether my approaches of both forward and inverse transform of gl_position are ok. Thanks.

Comment: It looks more or less correct, one thing you need to be aware of is that new GPUs are IEEE 754 compliant for single-precision FP (which is what Java also happens to use). Older GPUs were not. Even so, you shouldn't expect to transform vertices on the CPU and on the GPU and wind up with identical results; in fact, you shouldn't expect to get the same exact results twice on the GPU :) You usually get results with single-precision FP that are "good enough." FP was never actually designed to be precise, it solved a problem of representing very large ranges of values with acceptable precision loss.

Comment: Thanks Andon. Just wonder, openGL has the glunproject which does a similar reverse transform yeh ? Does that function yield "good-enough" results as well ?

Comment: Indeed, `gluUnProject (...)` actually uses double-precision, it would be more accurate than the math you're currently using.